# Solution to $x^\alpha + p x = q$?

Tags: polynomials, transcendental-equations

I was wondering if there was any tricks, similar in spirit to the Vieta's substitution, that would apply the equation
$$
x^\alpha + p x = q,
$$
where $p,q$ and $\alpha$ are real constants. In particular $\alpha$ is not necessarily an integer. The goal is to solve for $x$.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: x, p and q are variables? Give a bit more info if possible.

Comment: There are series solutions, e.g. see this Math Overflow question:
 http://mathoverflow.net/questions/113841/solution-of-certain-forms-of-equations

Comment: If $p+1=q$, then $x=1$ is a solution. If $\alpha$ is large, you can get approximate solutions. What can you tell us about $\alpha$, $p$, and $q$?

Comment: Thanks for the comments! $p$ and $q$ are just constants, and $x$ is the variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no known closed form general solution for a random integer $\alpha$. However, rewriting the

equation as $\color{blue}x=\sqrt[\large\alpha]{q-p\color{blue}x}~$ yields the following formula: $x=\sqrt[\large\alpha]{q-p~\sqrt[\large\alpha]{q-p~\sqrt[\large\alpha]{q-\ldots}}}$

Comment: Thanks! That's really helpful!

Answer (score -1):

Let me choose a for alpha to make notation easier

x^a = -px+q

(a)LN( x) = LN(-px+q)

x = e^{LN(-px+q)}/a

hope that helps

Comment: in the last equation you have $x$ in the RHS... This can not help...

Comment: let me try something else. please update question and add that X can not be on both side of the equation once you have solve for x

Comment: However, this might be a good *iteration* for $x$ starting at some initial value. There are standard tests for whether such an iteration can converge. Byt the way, you could just write the equation as $x = (-px+q)^{1/a}$.